# How do I type hint a question that returns a zip object?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I've got a function that takes an arbitrary amount of lists (or any iterables, for that matter) and sorts them as one. The code looks like this:

```
def sort_as_one(*args):
    return zip(*sorted(zip(*args)))
def main():
    list1 = [3, 1, 2, 4]
    list2 = ["a", "b", "d", "e"]
    list3 = [True, False, True, False]
    result = sort_as_one(list1, list2, list3)
    # <zip object at ...>
    print(result)
    list1, list2, list3 = result
    print(list1, list2, list3)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I accurately type hint the function output?

Comment: I mean, that makes sense, sure. However, how can I type hint the output "as-is"? That is, how should zip objects be type hinted?

Comment: are you sure that actually prints anything useful?  A zip object would print out like `<zip object ...>`

You might try `return [*zip(*sorted(zip(*args)))]`

Then type hint it as `def sort_as_one(*args) -> list`

Comment: @ekrall it doesn't matter *what it prints*, `zip` objects are very useful. Don't convert to a list just so you can type hint with `list`, that defeats the entire purpose of `zip` which is to return an efficient iterator

Comment: @ekrall **no** don't use `Any`

Comment: `typing.Iterator` seems most useful here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, you're right here. I have included the print statement just to show what kinda object the function returns.

Comment: I guess it would be silly except that the only thing the code does is print it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, my bad, I should have included the actual result. Will do that now, ty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `zip` object is an iterator - it follows the iterator protocol. Idiomatically, you would probably just typing hint it as such. In this case, you want to type hint it as a generic using a type variable:

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T")

def sort_as_one(*args: T) -> typing.Iterator[T]:
    return zip(*sorted(zip(*args)))
```

Note, if you are using variadic arguments, you have to only accept a single type. In this case, the best you can probably do in your case is use `Any` instead of `T`. But you should consider using only a function like the above in your code if you want to be able to use it with static type checkers.

Comment: This won't quite typecheck with the existing code (since he's using many types in the `args`, not just one generic) but this seems closest, yeah.

Comment: @AdamSmith Ah, misread that